# tableView:indexPathForCell returns nil

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, protocols

I am using the method `tableView:indexPathForCell` to implement a custom delegate that can dynamically resize a `UITableViewCell` based on the frame size of the `UIWebView` that is inside of it. The problem is that `tableView:indexPathForCell` is returning `nil` when I try to find out what the indexPath of a particular cell is:

```
- (void)trialSummaryTableViewCell:(TrialSummaryTableViewCell *)cell shouldAssignHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableV indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"tableV: %@\ncell: %@\nindexPath: %@", tableV, cell, indexPath); //<-- 
    // ...
}
```

Here, `tableV` does not return `nil`, cell does not return `nil`, but `indexPath` returns `nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am calling `-(void)trialSummaryTableViewCell` from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: I think that the cell is not created yet when you call **-(void)trialSummaryTableViewCell** from **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: @qPaul: So cell does not return nil because its an instance variable but it has not been added to the tableView it will not have an indexPath?

Comment: Yeah, I think so but it could be wrong.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It could be that the cell is not visible at this moment. tableView:indexPathForCell returns nil in this situation. I solved this using indexPathForRowAtPoint this method works even if the cell is not visible. The code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = textField.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cell.center];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just could not understand what is going on and why it works sometimes and not other times. What is interesting though is that this works even when the cell is not visible but on a newly created cell which was my problem.  I would insert a custom cell, start edit text field, scroll and put focus on another text field at which point on end editing would get triggered but I could not get index path. Going back and editing the first field and attempting the same thing again would work correctly.

Comment: good answer! :) Just a tip: `textField.superview.superview` is really bad design, try to avoid that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come this works when the cell is outside the view (I'm not clear about the relationship between cell.center and the table view bounds).

Comment: This is the exact solution

Comment: This should be the winning answer.

Comment: good answer, +1 for indexPathForRowAtPoint, but instead of using textField.superview.superview you should use below code: - (UITableViewCell*)parentCellForView:(UIView*)view
{
    if (!view)
        return nil;
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        return (UITableViewCell*)view;
    return [self parentCellFor:view.superview];
}

Comment: When I called `cell.center` I got this error:
`property 'center' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'`. Instead had to call `cell.layer.position`.

Comment: You could also use `textField.center`, then constructions such as `textField.superview.superview` are not needed.

Comment: @Koen `textField.center` returns the coordinates in its' superview system, not the tableview/collectionview, and therefor aren't correct coordinates. most likely this will result in the tableview/collectionview always returning row/item=1,section=1

Comment: Try to run same code on ios7 and ios 8. It will break because the view hierarchy in both the os is different for UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 13):

[tableV indexPathForCell:cell] returns nil if cell is not visible.

Also if you are calling "trialSummaryTableViewCell" from the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, you could easily pass indexPath also to the "trialSummaryTableViewCell" method.

Comment: But it does not return nil on ios < 4.3

Answer (score 5):

A small update, since Jorge Perez' answer will fail starting at iOS7 (since a `UIScrollView` has been inserted and calling `textField.superview.superview` won't work anymore).

You can retrieve the `NSIndexPath` like this:

```
//find the UITableViewCell superview
UIView *cell = textField;
while (cell && ![cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    cell = cell.superview;

//use the UITableViewCell superview to get the NSIndexPath
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cell.center];
```