# UITableView indexPathForCell return null when cell is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a lot tall rows (only 2-3 fit on the screen at a time), and some code to programmatically scroll to a specific row, when a specific view has been added to the UITableViewCell hierarchy. If the target row is visible on the screen, indexPathForCell returns the correct NSIndexPath. If the user would have to scroll down to see the target row, the NSIndexPath returned is null.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)scrollToLastSelection {
    if ((firstLabel) && (secondLabel)) {                
        UITableViewCell *targetCell = [self getTableViewCellFromSubview:secondLabel];
        NSIndexPath *targetCellIndexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:targetCell];
        CGRect targetCellRect = [myTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:targetCellIndexPath];

        NSLog(@"------ secondLabelCell: %@", targetCell);
        NSLog(@"------ secondIndexPath: %@", targetCellIndexPath);            

        [myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:targetCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *) getTableViewCellFromSubview:(UIView*)subview {
    UITableViewCell* tableViewCell = nil;    
    while (subview.superview != Nil) {
        if ([subview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            tableViewCell = (UITableViewCell*)subview.superview;
            break;
        } else {
            subview = subview.superview;
        }
    }    
    return tableViewCell;
}
```

Here is the output of the NSLog:

```
------ secondLabelCell: <UITableViewCell: 0x947c8f0; frame = (0 120; 320 10); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x947ca80>>
------ secondIndexPath: (null)
```

Does anyone know of a way to get the correct NSIndexPath of a UITableCell that is hidden? Or scroll to a UITableViewCell that is hidden?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I have found in some testing that if I scroll to (or past) the target cell (so its be rendered on the screen at some point), and from the original position (so the target cell is off screen again), the following works (thanks @Deepan):

```
UITableViewCell *targetCell = [self getTableViewCellFromSubview:secondLabel];
NSIndexPath *indexPathFromCellCenter = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:targetCell.center];
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathFromCellCenter atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems similar to the below question, as per the accepted answer you can consider using indexPathForRowAtPoint method to get the index.

[tableView:indexPathForCell returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930026/tableviewindexpathforcell-returns-nil)

Comment: thank you for the prompt response, however, that did not fix the issue. Instead of returning null, it returned and index path of 0, 0: 
`NSIndexPath *indexPathFromCellCenter = [myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:targetCell.center];
NSLog(@"------ indexPathFromCellCenter: %@", indexPathFromCellCenter);` 

Produced:

`------ indexPathFromCellCenter: <NSIndexPath: 0x94e80b0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}`